# Xamarin.iOS - The path XXX would result in a file outside of the app bundle and cannot be used

Tags: c#, build, xamarin

I just updated my xamarin tooling today, and I cannot build. I am getting these errors:

[image]

I have tried removing the references, re-adding and nothing seems to help.

Here is an example of the project file:

```
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\grayButton.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\greenButton%402x.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\greenButton.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\greenMenuButton%402x.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\greenMenuButton-selected%402x.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\greyMenuButton%402x.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\greyMenuButton-selected%402x.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\iPad\keypad%402x.png" />
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to Xamarin. This happened to be a bug in their release, please see these comments:

> Here's a build with the fix:
>       http://storage.bos.internalx.com/macios-mac-macios-cycle5-bug-29579/16/16f0890e3ef2262a03d52d29cb153095c7fe5be1/monotouch-8.10.1.66.pkg